# unable to upload files from my local machine on mobile real devices with browserstack local tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, browserstack

I'm using Browserstack to perform some test on a web app hosted on my local machine (Windows 10).
I've written tests using Mocha and selenium-webdriver.

I need to test a fileUpload, picking a file from my local environment. Browsing on Browserstack documentation I think I've found which should be the solution and it's working both with Windows and Mac OS configurations.

First of all I'm using a FileDetector

```
driver.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector);
```

Then I'm using sendKeys() on the fileInput WebElement

```
fileInput.sendKeys(imageFilePath);
```

Instead, when I run a test session on a real iOS device (iOS 13 - iPhone 8.0) I get:

```
WebDriverError: Appium error: File upload is not supported on real iOS devices
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
From: Task: remote.FileDetector.handleFile(/home/admin/BuildAgent/work/491c0dc9a984bb27/test/resources/images/imageUploader/partImage02.jpg)
    at WebDriver.schedule (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:807:17)
    at zip.addFile.then.then.then.encodedZip (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:586:27)
From: Task: WebElement.sendKeys()
    at WebElement.sendKeys (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:2185:43)
    at [...]
```

and on an Android real device (e.g. Android Pixel 4 - default browser):

```
UnsupportedOperationError: The URL '/wd/hub/session/45359c9c6c467dd8f00f6c1a638c993fe933bf67/file' did not map to a valid resource
    at parseHttpResponse (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:534:11)
    at doSend.then.response (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
From: Task: remote.FileDetector.handleFile(/home/admin/BuildAgent/work/491c0dc9a984bb27/test/resources/images/imageUploader/partImage02.jpg)
    at WebDriver.schedule (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:807:17)
    at zip.addFile.then.then.then.encodedZip (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:586:27)
From: Task: WebElement.sendKeys()
    at WebElement.sendKeys (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:2185:43)
    at [...]
```

Should I assume that file upload from local machine is not supported on Android real devices as well as on iOS, using those tools (Browserstack, selenium-webdriver) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalFileDetector supports only desktop browsers and not mobile devices. You can check here: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/9120

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks for the answer. It was like I've thought then!